# Poisson-Jensen Formula; zero or poles on $|z| = R$

Tags: complex-analysis

For the proof of the Poisson-Jensen formula, I want to show that the following equality holds:
$$\log(|z-a|) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \log(|Re^{i\theta} - a|) P(z, Re^{i\theta}) \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{2\pi},$$
where $a$ is a point on the circle of radius $R$ and $P(z,w) = \frac{|w|^2 - |z|^2}{|w-z|^2} = \text{Re}\left\{ \frac{w + z}{w-z} \right\}$ is the Poisson kernel. Normally this would be easy, however $\log{|Re^{i \theta} - a|}$ has a singularity, so the Poisson formula doesn't apply immediately.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It always applies. To prove, first prove when $a$ is not on the circle, then consider the limit, when $a$ tends to this circle.
The singularity is like $\log$ so the integral is convergent and the limit procedure is justified.